# Swift showing error when serializing data

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift5

When I try to serialize json data in swift I get this error
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)'`

Here is the code that is creating this issue:

```
request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: [])
```

my data variable looks something like this:

```
let data = ["first_name": "John", "last_name": "Riverson", "post_info: userPost(title: "Some title", date_published: "some date")] as [String: Any]
```

I issue is caused due to the userPost struct, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: At the least, you'd have to show the code for your `userPost` struct. I'd recommend you look into `Codable` rather than `JSONSerialization`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct that it's due to the struct.

As per the documentation on `JSONSerialization`:

> Foundation object that may be converted to JSON must have the
> following properties:
>
> - The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
> - All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
> - Numbers are not NaN or infinity.
>
> <sup>Ref:
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization</sup>

So you will need to convert the struct to dictionary to insert it here.

Something like:

```
let userPostDict: [String:Any] = //... your logic e.g. userPost.toDictionary
let data = ["first_name": "John", 
            "last_name" : "Riverson",
            "post_info" : userPostDict]
```

You could have a `toDictionary` computed property inside your `userPost` struct that gives you a `[String:Any]`

Example:

```
extension YourStruct {
  var toDictionary: [String:Any] {
      //make the dictionary & return here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the result of userPost is not available for JSON.

According to [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization)

> A Foundation object that may be converted to JSON must have the following properties:
>
> - The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
> - All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
> - Numbers are not NaN or infinity

If you want to make userPost could be accpeted by JSONSerialization, refer to [Using JSON with Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types?language=objc), and apply Codable to it.